# Insert arrow into a legend in R

Tags: r, plot, legend

Is there a way to insert symbol of arrow (other than simple  " -> ") into a legend in R?

```
legend(locator(1), c("1 -> 2", ...))
```

Thank you.

Comment: have a look at `expression`. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! So, it looks like this ... expression(x %->% y) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for suggestions. So, one of the possible answers how to insert arrow (i.e. to show transitions from x to y) into the legend may look like this:

```
plot.new() # empty plot
legend("topright", c(expression(x[1] %->% y[1]), expression(x[2]%->%y[2])),  col=4, bty="n")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you put this in without modification you will get an error, so why not post a complete example?

```
  legend(locator(1), c( expression(1 %->% 2), ...))
```

The appropriate place to look further is `?plotmath`.

Comment: All I see is a dash that's maybe a bit longer than the standard one. Are you asking how to make dashes that are longer that what you get with '-'"